# Value is not updated in excel after apply vlookup

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, pandas, vlookup

I have two data frames dataframe1 is:

```
USER_NAME  USER_ID    ROLE     CONTRACT_NO 

test1      123        role1                                                                             
test2      124        role2                                                                             
test3      125        role3                                                                             
test4      126        role4                                                                             
test5      127        role5                                                                             
test6      128        role6                                                                             
test7      129        role7
test8      130        role8
test9      131        role9
test10     132        role10
test11     133        role11
test12
test13
```

dataframe2 is this:

```
username      uid         Roles     Remarks
test1   123        role1     
test2   124        role2     
test3   125        role3     
test4   126        role4     
test5   127        role5     
test6   128        role6     
test7   129        role7     
test8   130        role8     
test9   131        role9     
test10  132        role10   
test11  133        role11
```

I apply a VLOOKUP formula  on dataframe1 to get all userID from dataframe2 and all roles from dataframe2 on basis of username. If username does not exist in dataframe2, userID and role should come blank in dataframe1 and this is happening using VLOOKUP something like this:

```
for x in range(2, sheet.max_row): #worksheet.write_formula('C'+str(x), '=VLOOKUP(B'+str(x)+',[Compiled_LDAP.xlsx]LDAP!$A$2:$D$10000,2,0)')
worksheet.write_formula('C'+str(x), '=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B'+str(x)+',[Compiled_LDAP.xlsx]LDAP!$A$2:$D$10000,2,0),"")')

for x in range(2, sheet.max_row): #worksheet.write_formula('D'+str(x),'=VLOOKUP(C'+str(x)+',[Compiled_LDAP.xlsx]LDAP!$B$2:$D$10000,2,0)') worksheet.write_formula('D'+str(x),'=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(C'+str(x)+',[Compiled_LDAP.xlsx]LDAP!$B$2:$D$10000,2,0),"")') writer.save()
```

Now I want the updated value in my data frame, after applying VLOOKUP, but value does not get updated. Also, if I load excel again in new data frame value is not updated. What other approach can I use?

Comment: Please can you be more specific in what you want? We cannot see which column is which in your tables, where do you want the values to be written? what is written? perhaps a screenshot to show the information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making assumptions because exact output is unclear as mentioned in the comments above. Thus, assuming the two DataFrames are already read from Excel into into Python and are ready for be joined. The code below uses `.merge()` instead of `vlookup` to bring data from `df2` into `df1`.

*Note:*

Additional columns can be added to the list for `left_on=[]` and `right_on=[]` to join on multiple columns. In the code below, the join is only using one column per DataFrame i.e. `left_on=['USER_NAME']` and `right_on=['username']`.

Code:

```
# Import libraries
import pandas as pd

# Create DataFrame
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'USER_NAME':['test1','test2','test3','test4','test5','test6','test7','test8','test9','test10','test11','test12','test13'],
    'USER_ID':[123,124,125,126,127,128,129,130,131,132,133,np.nan, np.nan],
    'ROLE': ['role1','role2','role3','role4','role5','role6','role7','role8','role9','role10','role11', np.nan,np.nan],
    'CONTRACT_NO':np.nan
})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'username':['test1','test2','test3','test4','test5','test6','test7','test8','test9','test10','test11'],
    'uid':[123,124,125,126,127,128,129,130,131,132,133],
    'roles': ['role1','role2','role3','role4','role5','role6','role7','role8','role9','role10','role11'],
    'remarks':np.nan
})

# Merge
df = df1.merge(df2, left_on=['USER_NAME'], right_on=['username'], how='left')
```

Output

```
print(df)

   USER_NAME  USER_ID    ROLE  CONTRACT_NO username    uid   roles  remarks
0      test1    123.0   role1          NaN    test1  123.0   role1      NaN
1      test2    124.0   role2          NaN    test2  124.0   role2      NaN
2      test3    125.0   role3          NaN    test3  125.0   role3      NaN
3      test4    126.0   role4          NaN    test4  126.0   role4      NaN
4      test5    127.0   role5          NaN    test5  127.0   role5      NaN
5      test6    128.0   role6          NaN    test6  128.0   role6      NaN
6      test7    129.0   role7          NaN    test7  129.0   role7      NaN
7      test8    130.0   role8          NaN    test8  130.0   role8      NaN
8      test9    131.0   role9          NaN    test9  131.0   role9      NaN
9     test10    132.0  role10          NaN   test10  132.0  role10      NaN
10    test11    133.0  role11          NaN   test11  133.0  role11      NaN
11    test12      NaN     NaN          NaN      NaN    NaN     NaN      NaN
12    test13      NaN     NaN          NaN      NaN    NaN     NaN      NaN
```